# Как запустить Android Studio под openJDK 8?

Tags: android, android-studio, java

Я загрузил `AndroidStudio 2.1` но в части экрана превью дисплея, показалась такая ошибка

[image]

Когда я перешел по ссылке то согласно ей у меня старая версия `JDK`, но чуть больше разобравшись я понял, что проблема скорее всего в том, что я использую `OpenJDK` и вот теперь мне нужно удалить ее и загрузить офф `JDK`.

Я пользуюсь Ubuntu 14.04, как я могу починить `AndroidStudio`?

Вот путь к новой openJDK 8

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И все равно я получаю туже ошибку...

Comment: 1 - [How to correctly remove OpenJDK/OpenJRE and set SunJDK/SunJRE as Default](http://askubuntu.com/questions/21131/how-to-correctly-remove-openjdk-openjre-and-set-sunjdk-sunjre-as-default) .
Там не самые свежие ответы, но суть думаю не изменилась.

2 - Проверьте вашу версию OpenJDK, может вам действительно обновится надо. Т.е версия < 1.8. Google вроде на OpenJDK хотели перейти из-за судебных тяжб с Oracle. Хотя может и не актуально уже

Comment: @UserName ну вот как раз в Android N  и перешли на OpenJDK)

Comment: Вам нужно просто обновится до Java 8, не важно open JDK или офф. от Oracle

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/java-ubuntu-apt-get-ru всегда делал как тут написано и проблем не было с установкой Java

Comment: @pavlofff я обновился до 8 JDK скрин добавил к описанию, но все равно проблема осталась... Есть предположения?

Comment: @xkor Вы имеете ввиду, что нет смысла переходить на Oracl JDK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема у вас осталась потому что у вас сама студия должна быть запущена под явой 1.8, а не просто указано в настройках какой JDK собирать проект. Переключить версию JDK для студии можно как описано [тут](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration).

Тоесть нужно добавить переменную среды `STUDIO_JDK` и прописать в неё путь к нужной вам версии JDK. Но лучше задать этот путь в переменную среды `JAVA_HOME` что бы сделать эту версию явы версией по умолчанию. Задать переменную `STUDIO_JDK` или `JAVA_HOME` на linux можно например в файле `/etc/environment`.

Comment: 3 раза перечитал, можете подсказать, если я правильно понял я создаю новый файл конфигурации `help-Edit Custom VM Options` , потом я переименовал папку с `AndroidStudio` на  `AndroidStudio2.1`, вроде так было написано, а дальше что нужно сделать? что добавлять в файл конфигурации, если я работаю на Ubuntu?

Comment: Эм, причем тут Custom VM Options и папку студии переименовывать? Вам просто нужно в переменную среды STUDIO_JDK засунуть путь к правильному JDK.

Comment: Никогда раньше этого не делал... Вот нашел ссылку http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/java вроде тут обьясняют как... Я ввел `export PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin` " потом `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64` потом `export JDK_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64` и `export JRE_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre`, но ничего не поменялось... У вас есть ссылка на какую нибудь пошаговую инструкцию? Я не могу понять как прописать этот путь(

Comment: Все разобрался в конце концов)) Вот так нужно было сделать sudo nano  /etc/environment
и в открывшемся файле дописать JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64 и все заработало))